# What's the reason that document.getElementById works but jquery doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question might seem elementary to some but I can't get my head around it. I am working on a XMLHttpRequest Ajax file upload. the first step is to selected the fileUpload element that is on my page and for some reason javascript works but not query, here's the following two lines:

```
var fileInput = $('#the-file'); //doesn't work
var fileInput = document.getElementById('the-file'); //works
```

do I have to specify a method after the jquery selector or sth? Because I can't see why else it wouldn't work, aren't they practically the same code?

I have added the jquery.js file on top (I have many lines of jquery working on other parts of my file so that can't be the issue.) and the document ready. I got it to work but am wondering the reason behind this.

Edit

By doesn't work I mean that with the jquery selector I get "undefined" in console log but with the javascript I get all the file information that I need.

Comment: firstly is the var in document ready? Secondly what version of jquery are you using? Third, is the id loaded after the page i.e through ajax?

Comment: @LiamSorsby: if the pure JavaScript version works, not being in a `$(document).ready` call isn't the issue here.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ?

Comment: yeah they are both in document ready. and I'm using v1.10.2

Comment: What error are you getting? Is jQuery working at all? Is it properly included in your document?

Comment: Just updated the problem

Comment: @LiamSorsby the id is static. I created a test file upload element at the end of my html page

Comment: So no errors? just an undefined return value? Tauts strange, even empty jQueries return objects...

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy the function doesn't return undefined. fileInput.files[0] is undefined but it cannot be because I selected a file

Comment: Are you typing just `$('#the-file')` in the console or `var fileInput = $('#the-file')` in the console? The latter will always print "undefined" regardless of what is returned.

Comment: @MutuYolbulan: The jQuery object is a wrapper for the actual DOM object. Have you tried `fileInput[0].files[0]` for the jQuery version?

Comment: maybe update the question with some html aswell?

Comment: What kind of HTML object is #the-file ? An input?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy fileInput[0].files[0] this is the solution. Thanks a lot, maybe write in the answer and I'll tick it as solved

Comment: So the issue isn't really that the selector is returning undefined, but you're using a jQuery object as it where a regular DOM object.

Comment: @p.s.w.g.: unless you surround it with brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the jQuery object is a wrapper for the actual DOM object - which in this case is an HTML `<input>` element which has the type `file`. Only the actual DOM object has the `files` property, not the jQuery object. You can access the DOM elements referenced by using numeric indexes, which will only be 0 in this situation. Therefore, this is the solution:

```
var fileInput = $('#the-file');
fileInput.files[0]; // TypeError: cannot read property '0' of undefined
fileInput[0].files[0]; // works
```

Of course, the jQuery way of doing it would be to use the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function, which gets the property of the first DOM object in the jQuery object:

```
fileInput.prop('files')[0];
```

Comment: That's not really true, the jQuery object is just a wrapper, and also has the `files` property, but you'd have to access it like you would any property in jQuery, with `prop()` -> http://jsfiddle.net/t4PyB/

Comment: @adeneo: true - I don't use jQuery much, that's the more "jQuery" way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that I don't know what you mean by "doesn't work" I would guess that its because whatever is using fileInput wants a DOM element and not a jquery object. Try this:

```
var fileInput = $('#the-file')[0];
```